# What’s the problem with highlighting the first line of a page in iBooks on iOS?

Tags: ipad, books, highlights

When I want to highlight the first line of a page in any book in iBooks on iOS. it starts to move the page slightly, and won’t  show the selection or the highlight.

Googling revealed that this is a “known bug”, and people typically go around it by changing the font size or otherwise changing the page layout so that the line they want to highlight is not the first on a page.

Now, okay, sure, the workaround exists. But what is the deal with this in the first place? It’s an old issue, and it feels more like a feature I can’t figure out. Perhaps the idea is that one could somehow highlight a phrase spanning two pages, and this weird interaction is a beginning of a workflow I can’t figure out. Maybe someone could give me a hint about what is going on?

Comment: Weird, I don't have any issue.  Opened a random book on my iPhone, pressed and held on the first word on the page, then drug the selection over the remainder of the line.  Worked as I would expect.   Guessing, but are you possibly not holding down long enough before dragging causing it to think you're turning the page?

Comment: @Charlie74 perhaps it’s actually iPad specific… i don’t have an iPhone to reproduce it, i probably should edit it in

Comment: no problem here, iPadOS 14.8, 11” iPP 2020: press and hold first word on page/paragraph and then drag to extend. I checked with random ePub and PDF. One observation: depending on how it was created text boxes in a PDF can overlap therefore it might be difficult to select the first word of a paragraph without changing the display zoom level first.